# TransactionScope Vs stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, race-condition

I have a web service hosted on multiple servers, as traffic increases, race conditions arise. We're using Entity Framework and host on Azure, I've been looking into either write the queries using `TransactionScope` or moving logic into a stored procedure and do a transaction there.

I was wondering what's the difference between using `TransactionScope` or a stored procedure? What are the best practices for this problem?

Comment: EF6 has "improved transaction support" https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Improved%20Transaction%20Support . So that might be an option for you too

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly discourage you from implementing transactions in stored procedures. This can greatly limit the flexibility you have in creating units of work (which a transaction is). Since you are using EF, I would encourage you to manage transactions in your business tier code. In this way, you have greater flexibility in defining and managing units of work.

Comment: I agree with you and, on top of that, I think having logic on code is more maintainable. But I was wondering, is there any benefit of having the sproc?

Comment: Perhaps one advantage is that transactions can be started and committed milliseconds faster than TransactionScope. Of course, if you didn't have a .NET business tier than procs would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

TransactionScope allows for transactions in your EF statements. so the entire linq statement will rollback. Whereas having transactions within SPROCS will only rollback whatever is processed within the sproc.

since you are using EF which allows you to interact with the database through Linq, you'd be as well going with TransactionScope IMO